# Increase step size on JSpinner when a certain key is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jspinner, event-listener

I want to be able to increase the step size on `JSpinner` when a certain key is pressed. What i tried so far was to put `KeyListener` on my spinner and when a certain key is pressed, change the value of the step size. When the key is release it should return to it's default.

I think i don't have to directly put the `KeyListener` onto the `JSpinner` but rather on its button.

I have honnestly no idea on how to achieve that. What confuse me here is the double `Listener`.

Here is the code i wrote for the `KeyListener` :

```
public class SpinnerKeyIncrement implements KeyListener {

    JSpinner spinner;
    SpinnerNumberModel spinnerModel;

    public SpinnerKeyIncrement(JSpinner s) {
        this.spinner = s;
        if(spinnerModel == null)
            spinnerModel = (SpinnerNumberModel) spinner.getModel();
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) {
            spinnerModel.setStepSize(.10);
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
            spinnerModel.setStepSize(1);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        spinnerModel.setStepSize(0.01);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry -- what exactly isn't working? As for the KeyListener bit, here it would always be better to use Key Bindings. If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a [minimal example program/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: KeyBinding? what exactly is that?

Comment: [What are Key Bindings?](https://www.google.com/?q=java+key+bindings&gws_rd=ssl#q=java+key+bindings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Again, I'd use Key Bindings to solve this, and I'd use bindings bound to the JSpinner's InputMap that's active when it has focus:

```
  InputMap inputMap = spinner.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
```

A working small example program could look like this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChangeStepSize extends JPanel {
   private static final String DOUBLE_STEP = "double step";
   public static final int SMALL_STEP_SIZE = 1;
   public static final int BIG_STEP_SIZE = 10;

   // bind to the "d" key, but you could use any key you'd like
   private static final int SPECIAL_KEY = KeyEvent.VK_D;
   private SpinnerNumberModel numberModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(50, 0, 100, 1);
   private JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(numberModel);

   public ChangeStepSize() {
      add(spinner);

      // set up key bindings. First get InputMap and ActionMap
      InputMap inputMap = spinner.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
      ActionMap actionMap = spinner.getActionMap();

      // next set bindings for when key is pressed
      boolean onKeyRelease = false;
      KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(SPECIAL_KEY, 0, onKeyRelease);
      inputMap.put(keyStroke, DOUBLE_STEP + onKeyRelease);
      actionMap.put(DOUBLE_STEP + onKeyRelease, new DoubleStepAction(onKeyRelease));

      // next set bindings for when key is released
      onKeyRelease = true;
      keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(SPECIAL_KEY, 0, onKeyRelease);
      inputMap.put(keyStroke, DOUBLE_STEP + onKeyRelease);
      actionMap.put(DOUBLE_STEP + onKeyRelease, new DoubleStepAction(onKeyRelease));
   }

   // our Action is passed in a parameter to indicate which state it
   // gets activated in: key press or key release
   private class DoubleStepAction extends AbstractAction {
      private boolean onKeyRelease;

      public DoubleStepAction(boolean onKeyRelease) {
         this.onKeyRelease = onKeyRelease;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (onKeyRelease) {
            numberModel.setStepSize(SMALL_STEP_SIZE);
         } else {
            numberModel.setStepSize(BIG_STEP_SIZE);
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ChangeStepSize mainPanel = new ChangeStepSize();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ChangeStepSize");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a good answer.
It's a bit more complicated than i thought it would be but i see how it works. Thanks, another day learning something :)

Comment: @Chax: Key Bindings are a bit more complicated than KeyListeners, but for this situation they work a whole lot better, and like most things, once you get used to them, coding them becomes second nature.

Comment: @Chax: also please look at the structure of my answer -- a minimal program that illustrates the problem and a solution. For future similar questions, consider posting a similar type of program, a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that we can compile and run and one that demonstrates the problem directly for us. This will make helping you **much** easier.

Comment: I thought that my question was simple enought not to have to make a small program. I'll try to remember that and post a minimal program example next time. Also is it possible to add another keyBinding for even bigger step? or would i need another AbstractAction class?

Comment: @Chax: but to solve it, **I** had to create one of these programs, which means extra effort on my part when it's **your** question. Your effort should be in making it as easy as possible for others to answer, so this should be done by you. You can add as many Key Bindings as you'd like or need.

Comment: Thanks again. Next time i'll post a question i'll put a Minimal example program for you to help me on ;)

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels Can i ask you one more question? It's from your example.

Comment: Why do you have to put a string in this line : `actionMap.put(**DOUBLE_STEP** + onKeyRelease, new DoubleStepAction(onKeyRelease));`. I have read multiple post and I don't get it.

Comment: @Chax: I don't think that it has to be a String. It has to be some object whose equals and hashCode methods have been overridden so that you can use it as a hash key to allow the InputMap element to be matched to a corresponding ActionMap element.

Comment: So each keyBinding has to have a different hash key? If by example i wanted to put two keyBind on the same Component i have to put different hash key.

Comment: @Chax: to be honest, I've not looked at the source code for Key Bindings and don't know if a HashMap is used, and I've always used Strings as my keys (and suggest that you do the same). But for each binding, yes, you should use a unique key. My code above uses two unique keys, since the boolean variable onKeyRelease changes from false to true between creation of the two bindings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75609/discussion-between-chax-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels).